# Pixels from plot: getframe is too slow

Tags: image, performance, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I need to do the following:

- I have a fixed environment with a point in it
- At each time step the point moves and I need to take a screenshot of the current status (environment + point)

What I do is

```
function getPixels(state)
    fig = figure('visible','off')
    hold all
    plot_environment()              % calls patch and other stuff 
    plot(state(1),state(2),'r+')
    f = getframe();
    data = f.cdata;
    close(fig)
```

The problem is that it is very slow (`0.6s` which for me is really too much).
I tried using `persistent fig` and I can go down to `0.4s`, still too much.

I read about using `print` or `hardcopy`, but it did not help. Even reducing the number of pixels by `-r20` (`1/5` of my default size) did not speed it up.

Any suggestion? Is there a faster way to get the pixels?

**EDIT: ADDITIONAL DETAILS**

The `state` is just a 2d point.

The environment is defined by some fixed known variables used to draw shapes. More specifically I have some points

```
points = [c11 c12
           c21 c22
           .....]
```

used to patch rectangles, circles and triangles. For this I use `patch` and [`circles`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45952-circle-plotter/content/circles_demo/html/circles_documentation.html).

So in the end I want to plot everything together and get the resulting **pixels**. Is there a way to do it without `getframe` or a way to speed it up?

**COMPLETE EXAMPLE**

It requires [`circles`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45952-circle-plotter/content/circles_demo/html/circles_documentation.html).

Launch `tic, getPixels([0.1, 0.2]'); toc`
It takes `0.43s` on average. The `getframe` command alone takes `0.29s`.

```
function data = getPixels(state)

fig = figure('visible','off');
hold all

c1 = [0.1 0.75; 
    0.45 0.75];
c2 = [0.45 0.4; 
    0.45 0.8];

radius = 0.1;

grey = [0.4,0.4,0.4];

% Circles
p = [c1; c2];
circles(p(:,1), p(:,2), radius, 'color', grey, 'edgecolor', grey)

% Rectangles
patch([0.1 0.45 0.45 0.1], [0.65 0.65 0.85 0.85], grey, 'EdgeAlpha', 0)
patch([0.35 0.55 0.55 0.35], [0.4 0.4 0.8 0.8], grey, 'EdgeAlpha', 0)

% Triangle
x = [0.95, 1.0, 1.0];
y = [1.0, 0.95, 1.0];
fill(x, y, 'r')

axis([0 1 0 1])

box on
axis square

% Point
plot(state(1),state(2),'ro','MarkerSize',8,'MarkerFaceColor','r'); 

f = getframe();
data = f.cdata;
close(fig)
```

Comment: Why are you plotting at all? If I'm not mistaken state should contain your plotted data, doesn't it?

Comment: The state contains only the `x-y` coordinates of the point (I made it clearer in the question). The environment is defined by additional known fixed variables which are used to plot patches and rectangles. I thought that in order to get the pixels (this is what I need) I have to first plot the image.

Comment: Can you provide a full example where getting the pixels takes 0.6 s?

Comment: Also, can you run your code with the `run and time` option to tell us where your code is taking so much time?

Comment: I added a full example and my execution time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the execution time of Matlab's `getframe()` function by a factor of ten. The trick consists of **not creating** a figure each time you call the `getPixels()` function **but using** an existing one. You may pass the figure handle *via* the function parameters. And use the Matlab's function `clf` that clears the current figure window between two calls.

---

EDIT

Here is an example of the way I play with `figure` et `getframe`.

The following performance chart

[image]

is given by

```
%%

clear al
close all
clc

nbSim = 10  %number of getframe calls
tElapsed = zeros(nbSim, 2); %two types of getting frames


%% METHOD 1: figure within loop

for ind_sim = 1:nbSim

    fig = figure;

    %some graphical elements
    hold all
    patch(rand(1,4), rand(1,4), rand(1,3), 'EdgeAlpha', 0)
    patch(rand(1,4), rand(1,4), rand(1,3), 'EdgeAlpha', 0)
    fill(rand(1,3), rand(1,3), 'r')
    plot(rand,rand,'ro','MarkerSize',8,'MarkerFaceColor','k');

    %some axes properties
    axis([0 1 0 1])
    box on
    axis square

    tStart = tic;
    f = getframe();
    tElapsed(ind_sim,1) = toc(tStart);
    data = f.cdata;
    close(fig)

end


%% METHOD 2: figure outside loop

fig = figure;
for ind_sim = 1:nbSim

    %some graphical elements
    hold all
    patch(rand(1,4), rand(1,4), rand(1,3), 'EdgeAlpha', 0)
    patch(rand(1,4), rand(1,4), rand(1,3), 'EdgeAlpha', 0)
    fill(rand(1,3), rand(1,3), 'r')
    plot(rand,rand,'ro','MarkerSize',8,'MarkerFaceColor','k');

    %some axes properties
    axis([0 1 0 1])
    box on
    axis square

    tStart = tic;
    f = getframe();
    tElapsed(ind_sim,2) = toc(tStart);
    data = f.cdata;
    clf

end
close(fig)

%% plot results

plot(tElapsed);
set(gca, 'YLim', [0 max(tElapsed(:))+0.1])
xlabel('Number of calls');
ylabel('Execution time');
legend({'within (method 1)';'outside (method 2)'});
title('GetFrame exectution time');
```

You have to drop the creation of a figure, even if it is declared not visible. This impairs the execution times.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Doing `fig = figure('visible','off');
tic, getPixels(fig,[0.3,0.4]'); toc` the times drops only to `0.34s`. Inside `getPixels` I do `clf(fig)` and `getframe(fig)`. Basically, all the time is now due to `getframe` (which is still very slow for my needs).

Comment: Here is the way I tackle the problem (see edit). I would love to have a faster method than this one.

Comment: It seems that the main problem is due to `fig = figure('visible','off');`, not to the creation of the figure. If you also set the visibility off, then there is almost no difference in terms of time. That's interesting, because I thought that would have made the code much faster. Anyway, thanks! 10x faster is nice (hope it would be possible to decrease the time even more, though)